# Using a transparent object to displace other objects that go behind it

Tags: animation, materials, transparency, displacement, shader-nodes

I want to make a transparent plane with an animated noise texture node that displaces anything that goes behind it in the viewport and render. Basically like a refractive window. I'm stuck on how to setup the displacement effect+transparent object.

Comment: so you can assign a glass shader to your plane? Maybe show a picture of the effect you'd like?

Comment: No, not a glass shader. I don't want the plane itself to be visible at all. But I want its noise texture to have a displacement effect on any object that passes behind it.

Comment: you don't want it to be visible but you want it to deform what's behind, so why not a glass shader?

Comment: Can you animate the displacement effect of a glass shader? My idea is to have the noise texture move around the object in an animation, so that the displacement of the other objects is always changing, producing a wavy/distorted effect on the affected objects, like viewing it through a flowing stream of water.

Comment: It strikes me that you might do this with geometry nodes.  Make your other objects instances and use raycasting to set their distance "above" the plane which you create via a grid that you displace.  realize the instances but not the plane and there you are.  Parts of [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/F2NcNJQZFqw) go into creating the plane and using raycasting.

Comment: sure, you can choose Coordinates > Object and choose an empty as object, when you'll move this empty it will make the noise move as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subdivide a plane and give it a *Displace* modifier with a *Cloud* noise as texture, set *Coordinates* to *Object* and choose an empty as object, animate the empty to make the noise move. If you use Eevee make sure that you've enabled all the options that will make your object transparent and refractive:

[image]

Comment: I experimented on my own with the suggestions you've given me, and I figured it out. Up until this point, I have never touched the glass shader, so I didn't ever think to try it, but that was indeed what I needed! It functioned how I wanted it to after turning on screen space refraction. What I needed to do to get the displacement effect was plug the noise texture node into the displacement input on the material output node, and animate the texture coordinates. [Here's the final result.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/553349591576346654/962790239032729730/displacement_window.gif)

Comment: yes it's another way to do it, I personally prefer the Displace modifier   ;)